# ¿Cómo enviar un array de php hacia una función de javascritpt usando onclick?

Tags: javascript, php, matriz

Quería saber si es posible enviar una matriz de PHP hacia una función que tengo en un archivo Javascript usando el evento `onclick` de un botón HTML.

¿Esto es posible hacerlo?, y si es correcto, ¿cómo lo puedo hacer?.

Intento pasar la matriz y no lo captura la función.

Mi matriz es ésta:

```
<?php
echo '<pre>';
print_r($maestros['data'][$key]);
die();
```

Y como resultado obtengo esto:

```
Array
(
    [idusuario_administrador] => 37
    [dsnombre_completo_usuario] => MAR�A CAMILA OSORIO
    [dscorreo_electronico] => test@test.com
    [perfil] => 5
    [id] => 35
    [titulo] => �Hola! Mi nombre es Mar�a Camilo Osorio, soy 
    [imagen] => m1.jpg
    [fecha] => 2022-02-24 14:31:45
)
```

Lo intento pasar a una función de Javascript de la siguiente manera:

```
<a type="button" class="btnModalUser" onclick="ejecutarModal('<?= $maestros['data'][$key]; ?>', 'degradadopeq<?= $tipoDegradado; ?>')"></a>
```

Pero el resultado en el HTMLde la página es el siguiente:

```
<a type="button" class="btnModalUser" onclick="ejecutarModal('Array', 'degradadopeq1')"></a>
```

Intente pasándole la función `json_encode()`, en el evento `onclick` pero no salía nada aparecía en vacío, ¿esto por qué ocurre y cómo puedo solucionarlo?

Nota: no es posible usar el `implode`, ya que en la propiedad de la matriz `titulo` es una descripción donde pueden ir comas, etc.

Mi código completo es:

```
 <?php
 foreach ($maestros['data'] as $key => $value) :

            $tipoDegradado = 1;
        ?>
            <div class="col-3 p-3" style="height: 500px;">
                <div class="card h-100 cardredondeada degradadopeq<?= $tipoDegradado; ?> ">
                    <a type="button" class="btnModalUser" onclick="ejecutarModal(<?= json_encode($maestros['data'][$key]) ?>, 'degradadopeq<?= $tipoDegradado; ?>')">
                        <img src="/img/<?= $value['imagen']; ?>" class="card-keymg-top" id="imgMaestro<?= $key ?>" alt="<?= utf8_encode($value['dsnombre_completo_usuario']); ?>" style="width: 100%; height: 350px;">
                        <div class=" card-body">
                            <center>
                                <h3 class="card-title text-white"><?= utf8_encode($value['dsnombre_completo_usuario']); ?></h3>
                            </center>
                        </div>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
```

El contenido de `$maestros` es el siguiente:

```
echo "<pre>";
var_export($maestros);
die();
```

Y el resultado es:

```
array (
  'error' => 0,
  'mensaje' => 'Se han encontrado los siguientes maestros.',
  'data' => 
  array (
    0 => 
    array (
      'idusuario_administrador' => '37',
      'dsnombre_completo_usuario' => 'MAR�A CAMILA OSORIO',
      'dscorreo_electronico' => 'test@test.com',
      'perfil' => '5',
      'id' => '35',
      'titulo' => '�Hola! Mi nombre es Mar�a Camilo Osorio, soy ',
      'imagen' => 'm1.jpg',
      'fecha' => '2022-02-24 14:31:45',
    ),
    1 => 
    array (
      'idusuario_administrador' => '38',
      'dsnombre_completo_usuario' => 'LUISA CARRIZOSA',
      'dscorreo_electronico' => 'test@test.com',
      'perfil' => '5',
      'id' => '36',
      'titulo' => 'prueba 1',
      'imagen' => 'm2.jpg',
      'fecha' => '2022-02-24 14:31:45',
    ),
    2 => 
    array (
      'idusuario_administrador' => '39',
      'dsnombre_completo_usuario' => 'CARLA PODEST�',
      'dscorreo_electronico' => 'test@test.com',
      'perfil' => '5',
      'id' => '37',
      'titulo' => 'prueba 2',
      'imagen' => 'm3.jpg',
      'fecha' => '2022-02-24 14:31:45',
    ),
    3 => 
    array (
      'idusuario_administrador' => '40',
      'dsnombre_completo_usuario' => 'JACKIE ARANGO',
      'dscorreo_electronico' => 'test@test.com',
      'perfil' => '5',
      'id' => '38',
      'titulo' => 'prueba 3',
      'imagen' => 'm4.jpg',
      'fecha' => '2022-02-24 14:31:45',
    ),
    4 => 
    array (
      'idusuario_administrador' => '41',
      'dsnombre_completo_usuario' => 'MIGUEL MORENA',
      'dscorreo_electronico' => 'test@test.com',
      'perfil' => '5',
      'id' => '39',
      'titulo' => 'prueba 4',
      'imagen' => 'm1.jpg',
      'fecha' => '2022-02-24 14:31:45',
    ),
    5 => 
    array (
      'idusuario_administrador' => '42',
      'dsnombre_completo_usuario' => 'HUMBERTO CADAVID',
      'dscorreo_electronico' => 'test@test.com',
      'perfil' => '5',
      'id' => '40',
      'titulo' => 'prueba 5',
      'imagen' => 'm6.jpg',
      'fecha' => '2022-02-24 14:31:45',
    ),
    6 => 
    array (
      'idusuario_administrador' => '43',
      'dsnombre_completo_usuario' => '�LVARO G�MEZ',
      'dscorreo_electronico' => 'test@test.com',
      'perfil' => '5',
      'id' => '41',
      'titulo' => 'prueba 6',
      'imagen' => 'm7.jpg',
      'fecha' => '2022-02-24 14:31:45',
    ),
    7 => 
    array (
      'idusuario_administrador' => '44',
      'dsnombre_completo_usuario' => 'ANDR�S VILLEGAS',
      'dscorreo_electronico' => 'test@test.com',
      'perfil' => '5',
      'id' => '42',
      'titulo' => 'prueba 7',
      'imagen' => 'm8.jpg',
      'fecha' => '2022-02-24 14:31:45',
    ),
  ),
)
```

Comment: Deberías usar codificación JSON, que es la representación nativa de datos en Javascript. Redacto respuesta.

Comment: @OscarGarcia intente colocarle el json_encode, pero no sale nada el resultado es un vacio, lo hice asi: json_encode($maestros['data'][$key]), en el evento onclick, y como resultado en el html de la pagina (usando el inspector), la funcion onclick sale vacio asi: onclick="funcion(' ', 'degradado1')

Comment: Como dato estoy usando un foreach para recorrer, los datos de la siguiente forma:  foreach ($maestros['data'] as $key => $value) :

Comment: ¿Estás recorriendo la matriz con un `foreach` en PHP? ¿Entonces para qué le pasas esos datos a una función javascript? ¿Podrías poner todo el código implicado? En mi respuesta te he puesto cómo resolver el problema, pero probablemente no estés haciendo bien algo más.

Comment: ¿Podrías hacer un `var_export($maestros)`? Un `print_r()` no sirve de mucho para reproducir un problema.

Comment: @OscarGarcia listo ya te publique el contenido de maestros

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deberías usar codificación JSON, que es la representación nativa de datos en Javascript. Recuerda cambiar el tipo de comillas dobles por las sencillas para que no se rompa el HTML.

Podrías generar los datos así:

```
<?php
$tipoDegradado = 1;
foreach ($maestros['data'] as $key => $value):
    /* Conversión a UTF-8 de todos los datos */
    $value = array_map('utf8_encode', $value);
?>
    <div class="col-3 p-3" style="height: 500px;">
        <div class="card h-100 cardredondeada degradadopeq<?= htmlspecialchars($tipoDegradado) ?> ">
            <a type="button" class="btnModalUser" onclick='ejecutarModal(<?= json_encode($maestros['data'][$key]) ?>, "degradadopeq<?= htmlspecialchars($tipoDegradado) ?>")'>
                <img src="/img/<?= htmlspecialchars($value['imagen']) ?>" class="card-keymg-top" id="imgMaestro<?= $key ?>" alt="<?= utf8_encode($value['dsnombre_completo_usuario']); ?>" style="width: 100%; height: 350px;">
                <div class=" card-body">
                    <center>
                        <h3 class="card-title text-white"><?= htmlspecialchars($value['dsnombre_completo_usuario']) ?></h3>
                    </center>
                </div>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Puedes ver el resultado en el siguiente enlace:

- http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/308ef4393d9504f3f9d73ec6012d07ab812fffd9

El resultado sería éste:

```js
const ejecutarModal = (parametros, valor) => {
  for (const propiedad in parametros) {
    console.log(propiedad, parametros[propiedad]);
  }
};
```

```css
div {
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="col-3 p-3" style="height: 500px;">
    <div class="card h-100 cardredondeada degradadopeq1 ">
        <a type="button" class="btnModalUser" onclick='ejecutarModal({"idusuario_administrador":"37","dsnombre_completo_usuario":"MAR\ufffdA CAMILA OSORIO","dscorreo_electronico":"test@test.com","perfil":"5","id":"35","titulo":"\ufffdHola! Mi nombre es Mar\ufffda Camilo Osorio, soy ","imagen":"m1.jpg","fecha":"2022-02-24 14:31:45"}, "degradadopeq1")'>
            <img src="/img/m1.jpg" class="card-keymg-top" id="imgMaestro0" alt="MARÃ¯Â¿Â½A CAMILA OSORIO" style="width: 100%; height: 350px;">
            <div class=" card-body">
                <center>
                    <h3 class="card-title text-white">MARï¿½A CAMILA OSORIO</h3>
                </center>
            </div>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-3 p-3" style="height: 500px;">
    <div class="card h-100 cardredondeada degradadopeq1 ">
        <a type="button" class="btnModalUser" onclick='ejecutarModal({"idusuario_administrador":"38","dsnombre_completo_usuario":"LUISA CARRIZOSA","dscorreo_electronico":"test@test.com","perfil":"5","id":"36","titulo":"prueba 1","imagen":"m2.jpg","fecha":"2022-02-24 14:31:45"}, "degradadopeq1")'>
            <img src="/img/m2.jpg" class="card-keymg-top" id="imgMaestro1" alt="LUISA CARRIZOSA" style="width: 100%; height: 350px;">
            <div class=" card-body">
                <center>
                    <h3 class="card-title text-white">LUISA CARRIZOSA</h3>
                </center>
            </div>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-3 p-3" style="height: 500px;">
    <div class="card h-100 cardredondeada degradadopeq1 ">
        <a type="button" class="btnModalUser" onclick='ejecutarModal({"idusuario_administrador":"39","dsnombre_completo_usuario":"CARLA PODEST\ufffd","dscorreo_electronico":"test@test.com","perfil":"5","id":"37","titulo":"prueba 2","imagen":"m3.jpg","fecha":"2022-02-24 14:31:45"}, "degradadopeq1")'>
            <img src="/img/m3.jpg" class="card-keymg-top" id="imgMaestro2" alt="CARLA PODESTÃ¯Â¿Â½" style="width: 100%; height: 350px;">
            <div class=" card-body">
                <center>
                    <h3 class="card-title text-white">CARLA PODESTï¿½</h3>
                </center>
            </div>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-3 p-3" style="height: 500px;">
    <div class="card h-100 cardredondeada degradadopeq1 ">
        <a type="button" class="btnModalUser" onclick='ejecutarModal({"idusuario_administrador":"40","dsnombre_completo_usuario":"JACKIE ARANGO","dscorreo_electronico":"test@test.com","perfil":"5","id":"38","titulo":"prueba 3","imagen":"m4.jpg","fecha":"2022-02-24 14:31:45"}, "degradadopeq1")'>
            <img src="/img/m4.jpg" class="card-keymg-top" id="imgMaestro3" alt="JACKIE ARANGO" style="width: 100%; height: 350px;">
            <div class=" card-body">
                <center>
                    <h3 class="card-title text-white">JACKIE ARANGO</h3>
                </center>
            </div>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-3 p-3" style="height: 500px;">
    <div class="card h-100 cardredondeada degradadopeq1 ">
        <a type="button" class="btnModalUser" onclick='ejecutarModal({"idusuario_administrador":"41","dsnombre_completo_usuario":"MIGUEL MORENA","dscorreo_electronico":"test@test.com","perfil":"5","id":"39","titulo":"prueba 4","imagen":"m1.jpg","fecha":"2022-02-24 14:31:45"}, "degradadopeq1")'>
            <img src="/img/m1.jpg" class="card-keymg-top" id="imgMaestro4" alt="MIGUEL MORENA" style="width: 100%; height: 350px;">
            <div class=" card-body">
                <center>
                    <h3 class="card-title text-white">MIGUEL MORENA</h3>
                </center>
            </div>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-3 p-3" style="height: 500px;">
    <div class="card h-100 cardredondeada degradadopeq1 ">
        <a type="button" class="btnModalUser" onclick='ejecutarModal({"idusuario_administrador":"42","dsnombre_completo_usuario":"HUMBERTO CADAVID","dscorreo_electronico":"test@test.com","perfil":"5","id":"40","titulo":"prueba 5","imagen":"m6.jpg","fecha":"2022-02-24 14:31:45"}, "degradadopeq1")'>
            <img src="/img/m6.jpg" class="card-keymg-top" id="imgMaestro5" alt="HUMBERTO CADAVID" style="width: 100%; height: 350px;">
            <div class=" card-body">
                <center>
                    <h3 class="card-title text-white">HUMBERTO CADAVID</h3>
                </center>
            </div>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-3 p-3" style="height: 500px;">
    <div class="card h-100 cardredondeada degradadopeq1 ">
        <a type="button" class="btnModalUser" onclick='ejecutarModal({"idusuario_administrador":"43","dsnombre_completo_usuario":"\ufffdLVARO G\ufffdMEZ","dscorreo_electronico":"test@test.com","perfil":"5","id":"41","titulo":"prueba 6","imagen":"m7.jpg","fecha":"2022-02-24 14:31:45"}, "degradadopeq1")'>
            <img src="/img/m7.jpg" class="card-keymg-top" id="imgMaestro6" alt="Ã¯Â¿Â½LVARO GÃ¯Â¿Â½MEZ" style="width: 100%; height: 350px;">
            <div class=" card-body">
                <center>
                    <h3 class="card-title text-white">ï¿½LVARO Gï¿½MEZ</h3>
                </center>
            </div>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-3 p-3" style="height: 500px;">
    <div class="card h-100 cardredondeada degradadopeq1 ">
        <a type="button" class="btnModalUser" onclick='ejecutarModal({"idusuario_administrador":"44","dsnombre_completo_usuario":"ANDR\ufffdS VILLEGAS","dscorreo_electronico":"test@test.com","perfil":"5","id":"42","titulo":"prueba 7","imagen":"m8.jpg","fecha":"2022-02-24 14:31:45"}, "degradadopeq1")'>
            <img src="/img/m8.jpg" class="card-keymg-top" id="imgMaestro7" alt="ANDRÃ¯Â¿Â½S VILLEGAS" style="width: 100%; height: 350px;">
            <div class=" card-body">
                <center>
                    <h3 class="card-title text-white">ANDRï¿½S VILLEGAS</h3>
                </center>
            </div>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

PD: He usado `array_map()` para convertir los datos de la matriz de Latin1 a UTF-8, pero si esos datos los estás obteniendo de una base de datos deberías corregirlo en la configuración dela conexión. También usado `htmlspecialchars()` para enviar datos al navegador.

Comment: Amigo por que intento hacer el json_encode y no me lista nada, hago echo json_encode($maestros['data'][$key], y no imprime nada?

Comment: No lo sé, con el poco código que compartes poco más puedo hacer. ¿Podrías compartir un [ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: Listo ya modifico mi pregunta

Comment: Imagino que solucionaste el problema. Por lo que copiaste en la pregunta, imagino que el problema fue las comillas, aún mantenías comillas dobles. ¿Modificaste algo más para hacerlo funcionar?

Comment: Gracias amigo me funciono tu respuesta lo que modifique para que funcionara el evento fue colocar el array $value, y no $maestros['data'][$key]